# Execution limit and Memory limit errors even i changed to 1024M and 600(cache.php,load.php)?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, errors

```
    Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Infosec/wp-includes/cache.php on line 548

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Infosec/wp-includes/load.php on line 677

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Infosec/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 291
```

I had incresed to the 1024Mb and time to 600 but no use , the error happening at the cache and load.php

What effected my theme to cause this error. Do commentlines cause the errors

I am using Mamp, do i should work on real server when size increased

Answer (score 1):

1024 MB is not enough is what I understand from the error message. Try increasing it more